# How do I fire events after user verification?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

First off, I've followed every step in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/verification) without success. I then dug into the `getVerification` method handling email verification requests, and went all the way down to Jrean\UserVerification\UserVerification, where they have `wasVerified($user)`

```
$user->verification_token = null;

    $user->verified = true;

    $user->verified_at = now();

    $this->updateUser($user);

    event(new UserVerified($user));
```

So I swapped out the default event in the docs, which I was dispatching in my override of `getVerification` in RegisterController

default EventServiceProvider from docs

```
protected $listen = [
    'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Verified' => [ // then replaced event name with 'Jrean\UserVerification\Events\UserVerified'
        'App\Listeners\LogVerifiedUser',
    ],
];
```

I also tried listening to both events i.e. firing mine as well in my RegisterController

```
use VerifiesUsers {

  getVerification as parentVerification;
}


public function getVerification(Request $request, $token) {

    $this->parentVerification($request, $token);

    event(new Verified(\Auth::user()));
```

Then I `dd`ed something (either in the listener or before manually emitting the event in the controller above) and the DB insert in my listener ran seamlessly.

However, there was no redirect afterwards. I removed the `dd`, believing all to be well and fine, now the behaviour has become even more inscrutable: after "verification", those columns in `wasVerified()` never get updated in that user's row. Everything is stagnant, yet the user can perform all actions accessible to a verified user (in spite of those routes being protected with the "verified" middleware, which is also registered in the routes middleware in the Kernel). At the same time, either none of the events fire or the listener is deaf.

I tried following the [mocking events docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mocking#event-fake) but I don't know how to go about replicating user verification in a test environment. But even if I did, it will just tell me whether the event is fired in the first place, not directly solving the problem at hand.

Finally, I tried manually calling my target handler (both with and without the aid of events) but nothing happens. It just gets into the parent verifier and redirects to the homepage.

Is there any other way of running a desired action after a user is verified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had nothing to do with the package. The RegisterController was unfortunately guarded by a "guest" middleware. "guest" middleware checks if you're logged in and takes you "/home". Meanwhile, inside that `getVerification` method, users are logged in by default after registration

```
    if (config('user-verification.auto-login') === true) {
        auth()->loginUsingId($user->id);
    }
```

The docs are also wrong about what event to listen to. The correct key should be 'Jrean\UserVerification\Events\UserVerified'

Answer (score 0):

At the VerificationController.php file, you can change where the users get redirected to after the verification. You could try changing that to a custom place and there place any code you want.

Comment: This doesn't work. VerificationController.php handles pre-verification concerns. The properties that should run after verification is either $redirectAfterVerification or redirectAfterVerification() method on the RegisterController. I have tried all 3 approaches but it doesn't alter the eventual redirect route. It just ends up at '/home' all the same

Comment: I've cleared both the application and route caches but it still redirects to '/home' regardless. Assuming the verification library is broken, how do I go about reinstalling it?